# HL-2240 Brother not printing at margins

Tags: printing, brother

It seems like the left margin is fine, but the top and right margins over-run making it seem like the page is cut-off at top and right. It's as if the page were printed too high and too far right.

I installed the printer using the drivers from the Brother website with the following procedure:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cups
sudo apt-get install cups
sudo apt-get install  ia32-libs lib32stdc++6
sudo dpkg -i --force-all ~/Downloads/hl2240lpr-2.1.0-1.i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all ~/Downloads/cupswrapperHL2240-2.0.4-2.i386.deb
```

In properties I have manually set the page size to "Letter". (It defaults to A4).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

finally, according to my [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1184663)

we have at least a reliable workaround, which consists of changing the default renderer using the following command

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER-NAME -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops
```

of course, you have to change PRINTER-NAME accordingly to your printer

give it a try, and just in case you want to go back to the default settings you can use

```
lpadmin -p PRINTER-NAME -R pdftops-renderer-default
```

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know if it worked. My printer has just been sitting there collecting dust.

Comment: Thanks! This works on Debian Jessie x64 with CUPS 1.7.1 perfectly. (HL2270DW over WiFi with binary driver). Apart from the fact that printing 2 sides per side does not...

Comment: Yup a quick `lpadmin -p HL2250DN -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops` worked for our HL2250DN. How strange.

Comment: Worked for me with a Brother MFC-J650DW as well: `lpadmin -p "Brother_MFC_J650DW" -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have that exact same model printer and the Brother drivers didn't work for me either. I just let the wizard set it up as a 2170w and it works fine for me. Don't uninstall the driver you have already added, just add a new printer and let Ubuntu pick the driver for you, print to it, and if it works you can just change the default printer to that one. That way if it works, great, if it dosen't, no loss.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work that way - thanks for trying tho! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Brother HL-2270DW and I solved installing it as "Generic PCL Laser Printer", however a workaround (not so convenient in my opinion) for the Brother original driver is to print your document as .ps file and then print that file.

This issue is related to CUPS 1.6.x introduced with Ubuntu 12.10, because with Ubuntu 12.04 the printing margins are OK.

Answer (score 1):

In the print dialog:

- Go to the "**Advanced**" tab
- Set "**Page Margins/Offsets**" to "**Driver Default**"