# Brother HL-2240 printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing

Where can I find a good driver for a brother hl-2240 printer. The one from Brother won't load on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please be more specific about "won't load". And what are your indications it doesn't work already right out of the box when connecting? Most printers "just work". Do you get any error or isn't it recognised at all? Etcetera etcetera. Please **edit** your question to include all this information.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/284441/88802

Comment: the one from Brother is for Windows only... got a similar printer...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The Brother HL-2240 cups drivers won't load into the ubuntu 12.o4 driver directory.

Comment: @OzzieM Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found Brother printers among the easiest to install under Ubuntu even if one isn't auto-recognized by the system. You can obtain the driver as well as the driver install tool on [this](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2240_us_eu&os=128) page.

Which looks like this:

[image]